# Is it possible to add instances at run time for Multi Instance Sequential?

Tags: activiti

I have a process that uses "Call Activity" to call a process and creates a set number of sequential Multi instances of it, however, while the main process is still running it may be required to add additional loops.

So question is, is possible to achieve this on activiti (Modeling or Coding)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No as far as I am aware, that wouldn't be a simple task. You can always finish the first set of iterations and create a process variable to go into a second loop, when the Call Activity finishes.